# Hiding a div with jQuery depending on position on parent div

Tags: jquery

I have this div that I want to hide when it's near the left side of the parent div. This is how it looks like:

```
┌-----------------------
| ┌------------------┐ 
|◄|                  |
| |                  |
| |                  |
| |                  |
| |                  |
| └------------------┘
└-----------------------
```

So I have the arrow div nested on another div. What I want to do is hide that arrow div when it's near the container div's left side. Is there any way to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: What will be the other elements ? Give more details.

Comment: What do you mean other elements?

Comment: how do you intend to render the arrow? is it a image? etc?

Comment: @melaos: It's a div with a background-image of an arrow.

Comment: that should be simple, just name your div with a proper id and you can easily shift the css of the div with .css{"attr","value"}. just becareful of cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could use position() or offset() to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In logic, you would have to take the position, and make an approach from time to time, and / or when a trigger event .. it is up to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
       <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                            var B = $( '#b' ).position();
                            var C = $( '#c' ).position();
                            alert ( B.left ) ;
                            alert ( C.left ) ;
                     });
              </script>
       </head>
       <body>
              <div id="a">
                     A
                     <div id="b">
                            B
                            <div id="c">
                                   C
                            </div>
                     </div>
              </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick example of what is being suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/8YC8y/

Comment: What if the inner container is a class? I tried putting the arrow inside the inner_container div and It's still working. I changed the inner_container into a class and it's still working. but when I make another similar div, only the first div hides the arrow. http://jsfiddle.net/8PGwp/

Comment: Figured it out on my own. Thanks for the help! :D